# Find E-Mail Adresses in a text

Tags: java, regex

Can somebody tell me how to find E-Mail Adresses in a text?

Example text:

> "Hey,
>
> I just blahblah
>
> E-Mail: lolcat@catinator.com
>
> Another would be lolcat2@catinator.com"

So the output is:

```
lolcat@catinator.com
lolcat2@catinator.com
```

I tried Regex, but I got no idea how I can do this over an entire text...

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("asd@asdasd.de".toUpperCase());

if(matcher.matches()){
    System.out.println("Mail found!");
}else{
    System.out.println("No Mail...");
}
```

Can somebody help me? :(

Greetings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're so many different types of email address formats that it is hard to match all of them. A simple (*for your structured data*) but no so effective approach would be the following:

```
String s  = "Hey,\n" +
            "I just blahblah\n" +
            "E-Mail: lolcat@catinator.com\n" +
            "Another would be lolcat2@catinator.com";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S+@\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output

```
lolcat@catinator.com
lolcat2@catinator.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the regex expression you have provided. But if it is good and serves your purpose then you can use following to extract the string,

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("asd@asdasd.de".toUpperCase());
String result;
while (matcher.find()) { 
    // result now will contain  the email address
    result = matcher .group();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: `{2,4}` won't work with the new domain names that are technically possible.

Comment: @k_g, REGEX : That's why I intentionally clarified about it's validity on my answer and provided only the way to get the required string from Pattern match.